# SystemVerilog - Can I pass unknown size of unpacked array of packed array to a function?

Tags: function, system-verilog

I know that I can pass unknown size of packed array to function and change the array by inout.
For example:
The function is:

```
function void foo_arr_bit (inout bit [31:0] mem, input int size, string  mem_name);
      for (int i=0; i< size(); i++)
           mem[i] = my_randomize_int(mem[i], mem_name);     
endfunction: foo_arr_bit
```

Call the function:

```
foo_arr_bit (data_bit, 8, "data_bit");
```

But can I pass unknown size of unpacked array of packed array to a function?
I tried the following:

```
function void foo_arr_bit (int seed, inout bit [31:0] q [$], input string mem_name, int arr_size, const ref int vec_bit_siz);
      for (int i=0; i< size(); i++)
           mem[i] = my_randomize_int(mem[i], mem_name);     
endfunction: foo_arr_bit
```

Call the function:

```
foo_arr_bit (seed, arr_vec_bit, "arr_vec_bit", t_data_bit, 9, arr_vec_b_size);
```

Where:

```
   bit [9:0]   arr_vec_bit [$];
   int arr_vec_b_size = 10;
```

And got the following error:

** Error (suppressible): (vlog-7034) ..\sv\trx.sv(31): Array assignment to type 'bit[31:0] $[$]' from type 'bit[9:0] $[$]': Ar
. 'q' of 'my_randomize_array_vec_bit': Element widths (32, 10) don't match

Where line 32 is the function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a better practice to use **ref** when you pass large arrays/queues to functions where you expect them to modify its contents. (It takes a smaller memory footprint.) Thus using *ref* instead of *inout* should work for you:

```
class foo_test();   
  bit [31:0] m_queue [$];

  function void foo_fill();
    m_queue.push_front(32'h0000_CAFE);
    foo(m_queue);   
  endfunction: foo_fill

  function void foo (ref bit [31:0] p_queue [$]);
    foreach(p_queue[i]) $display($sformatf("0x%8h", p_queue[i]));
  endfunction: foo

endclass: foo_test
```

By the way if you are using a queue or a dynamic array you can utilize the *.size()* function and skip the size parameter altogether.